# C++ WinInet, как зашифровать заголовок для POST запроса?

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть, wininet

Привет!

Сервер требует зашифровать заголовок с HMAC-SHA512

Key - Your API key

Sign - The query's POST data signed by your key's "secret" according to the HMAC-SHA512 method.

Кроме этого в заголовке должен быть параметр nonce, который, как подсказали, является счетчиком.

Additionally, all queries must include a "nonce" POST parameter. The nonce parameter is an integer which must always be greater than the previous nonce used.

Неясно, в какой последовательности и как именно зашифровать и собрать заголовок, отвечающий этим требованиям.

Есть пример на Python, но мне по-прежнему не ясно, как такое же сделать на С++:

```
req['command'] = command
            req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)
            post_data = urllib.urlencode(req)

            sign = hmac.new(self.Secret, post_data, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
            headers = {
                'Sign': sign,
                'Key': self.APIKey
            }

            ret = urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers))
            jsonRet = json.loads(ret.read())
```

Спасибо!

Comment: Какую из API функций вы выбрали из wininet?

Comment: nonce - судя из описания счётчик.

Comment: InternetOpen -> InternetConnect -> HttpOpenRequest -> HttpSendRequest -> InternetReadFile, и затем все закрываем InternetCloseHandle соответсвенно

Comment: Насколько я понял, заголовок передаётся в HttpSendRequest https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384247(v=vs.85).aspx, но вопрос в том, как его построить с учетом требований - примеров найти не смог.

Comment: Для http протокола нет понятия "подписаный" запрос, это уже "приспособлено" к нему со-стороны - читайте внимательно требования к вашей задаче. Если у вас вопрос "как передать http post запрос с параметрами через wininet" - то это уже другой вопрос - тогда внесите правку в заголовок.

Comment: Шифрование - это тоже отдельный вопрос. Ваша "задача" состоит уже из 3-х пунктов, врядли вам на все три ответят. Я считаю вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: Отредактировал, так же нашёл пример на пайтоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря по шагам, что делает код Python на каждой строке, воспроизвёл на С++, всё получилось.

Для шифрования берём https://www.cryptopp.com/

```
string postData("command=" + command + "&nonce=" + std::to_string(time(0) * 1000));
string mac;
string sign;

SecByteBlock key((const byte*)secret.data(), secret.length());  
HMAC<SHA512> hmac(key, key.size());  
StringSource(postData, true, new HashFilter(hmac, new StringSink(mac)));  
StringSource(mac, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(sign), false));
```

Затем собираем заголовок вот так:

```
string header("Key: " + apiKey + "\r\nSign: " + 
sign + "\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
```

И шлем POST запрос, всё работает.